# How can I skip over an entry in the browser's back button?

Tags: javascript, html, razor, browser, browser-history

I'm working on a web app that requires someone to submit a form. To submit the form, they click on a button that takes them to an external page. I do not have access to this page. Upon submission, they are returned to the page they came from (that I control).

My problem is, if the user then clicks the back button, it gives them an Error because the external page does not allow it for security reasons. That's not what I want the user to experience.

Webpages are fairly new to me, so I'm not entirely knowledgeable about how to achieve this. I know you can prevent something being added to history with replaceState(), but I do not have access to the external page's code in order for that to work.

I have a back button embedded in the page where I was able to skip over that error by going back 2 pages instead of 1. But this does not affect the browser's back button. Is there any way to redirect the browser or skip over this external page if I'm going back to a page I control?

Current flow: Page 1 -> External Site Submission -> Page 2 -> Browser Back Button -> Error

Desired flow: Page 1 -> External Site Submission -> Page 2 -> Browser Back Button -> Page 1

Comment: In the error page, you can just include that the user should click the back button once again

Comment: @mplungjan I thought location.replace would have to be used on the page you do not want. For example, Inside of the external site submission page, before it closed out, it would do location.replace() with the other page I need. But I do not have access to the external pages code

Comment: @Rojo I do not have access to the error page. It is the external site showing it.

Comment: That is what I meant. On the page you want to skip you do location replace the next page

Comment: @mplungjan "But I do not have access to the external pages code"

Comment: Instead of telling the user to press the back button, you can just add a link to the first page on the second page, right?

Comment: If you cannot do that then you need a proxy

Comment: I have an embedded back button that redirects the page like I want if the user clicks it. This is just for the scenario of the browser's back button. If the user sticks to the web-page controls they are fine. If they use the browser back button out of habit, then I am not sure how to fix the error. It does work by clicking back twice, but still want to avoid the second click as the user might not know. Can you elaborate on using a proxy?

Comment: You have, on your server, a process that is called from page 1 instead of external. That server will do an http request to external site with all the information from page 1 as if a user had executed the request from their browser. Then the same process receives the response and shows it on page 2 of your site. Then if the user presses the back button from page 2, they go to page 1